# Fill by group and between two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill all rows between two values by `group`. For each `group`, `var1` has two values equal to `1`, and I want to fill the missing rows between the two `1`s. `var1` represents what I have, `var2` represents what I want, `var3` shows what I am obtaining with my code, but it is not what I want (different from `var2`):

```
var1 group var2 var3
NaN  1     NaN  NaN
NaN  1     NaN  NaN
1    1     1    1
NaN  1     1    1
NaN  1     1    1
1    1     1    1
NaN  1     NaN  1
NaN  1     NaN  1   
1    2     1    1
NaN  2     1    1
1    2     1    1
NaN  2     NaN  1
```

My code:

```py
df.var3 = df.groupby('group')['var1'].bffill()
```

Comment: is the value always 1 or NaN? If not, can you provide an example?

Comment: It's always 1 or NaN

Comment: Then my answer below will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values are only 1 or NaN, you can [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and [`groupby.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) and only keep the values that are identical:

```
g = df.groupby('group')['var1']

s1 = g.ffill()
s2 = g.bfill()

df['var2'] = s1.where(s1.eq(s2))
```

Output:

```
    var1  group  var2
0    NaN      1   NaN
1    NaN      1   NaN
2    1.0      1   1.0
3    NaN      1   1.0
4    NaN      1   1.0
5    1.0      1   1.0
6    NaN      1   NaN
7    NaN      1   NaN
8    1.0      2   1.0
9    NaN      2   1.0
10   1.0      2   1.0
11   NaN      2   NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
    var1  group  var2  ffill  bfill
0    NaN      1   NaN    NaN    1.0
1    NaN      1   NaN    NaN    1.0
2    1.0      1   1.0    1.0    1.0
3    NaN      1   1.0    1.0    1.0
4    NaN      1   1.0    1.0    1.0
5    1.0      1   1.0    1.0    1.0
6    NaN      1   NaN    1.0    NaN
7    NaN      1   NaN    1.0    NaN
8    1.0      2   1.0    1.0    1.0
9    NaN      2   1.0    1.0    1.0
10   1.0      2   1.0    1.0    1.0
11   NaN      2   NaN    1.0    NaN
```